# Regular expression to check if a string contains a phone number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

What is the regular expression to match a phone number inside a TEXT field in a table?
I am trying to match mainly US numbers.

What I have found so far is this:

```
"07[^0-9]*123[^0-9]*456"
```

But this one tries to match ONLY phone numbers. What I am trying to do is match TEXT fields that **contain** phone numbers.

This is my query:

```
select count(*) as phone_number from myTable 
where Query REGEXP "07[^0-9]*123[^0-9]*456";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide examples of phone numbers that you want to match, and perhaps even the text fields that they might be in.

Comment: Define "phone number". If you can you're probably doing it wrong. The best you can hope for is *probable* phone numbers. Is `1.877.888.8888` a valid number? How about `1(900) 222-3333 x 2400`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @tadman yes these numbers are valid. as long as the string contains any kind of phone numbers. the rest of the string can contain anything

Comment: Are you comparing with `REGEXP`? Then text **containing** the pattern you're looking for should be returned just fine, unless you explicitly add `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of your pattern ...

Comment: Seeing the exact full `SELECT` statement you're using may clarify things a bit

Comment: just added my query to the question